# Java LocalTime.parse working in spring boot on local PC but not working in Docker container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

Title describes my problem. I'm feeling really dumb now because it's probably a minor, tiny issue.

I've been stuck on this for almost 2 days. The app I'm building is much bigger, with docker compose to start the postgres container, but the problem can be recreated by creating a new (java 21, maven) spring boot project with only spring web as its dependency. In the class with @SpringBootApplication, add the following:

```
@Bean
ApplicationRunner applicationRunner() {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a");
        return args -> {
            System.out.println("Parsed: 12:30 pm -> " + LocalTime.parse("12:30 p.m.", formatter));
        };
}
```

When I run it with intellij or `./mvnw spring-boot:run`, or in just a regular java class (without the annotation) it runs.

But, when I use this docker file:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:21-jdk-alpine
COPY . /app/
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["./mvnw", "spring-boot:run", "-Dskiptests"]
```

And build with `docker build -t localtime:1.0 .`, then run with: `docker run -p 1234:8080 --name localtime-container localtime:1.0`. This is what I get after the regular spring startup log messages:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-02-20T06:08:00.097Z ERROR 71 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '12:30 p.m.' could not be parsed at index 6
        at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2108) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:2010) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.time.LocalTime.parse(LocalTime.java:473) ~[na:na]
        at org.example.localtimedemo.LocaltimeDemoApplication.lambda$applicationRunner$0(LocaltimeDemoApplication.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunner$4(SpringApplication.java:786) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.acceptWithException(ThrowingConsumer.java:83) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:60) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:88) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:798) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:786) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunners$3(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:510) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:341) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.example.localtimedemo.LocaltimeDemoApplication.main(LocaltimeDemoApplication.java:15) ~[classes/:na]

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  26.863 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-02-20T06:08:00Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.2:run (default-cli) on project localtime-demo: Process terminated with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

BUTTTT, When I uncomment the sout statement, it runs fine.

I've tried using different Dockerfiles, same problem.

Does anyone know what's going on and how to fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### tl;dr

```
DateTimeFormatter
    .ofPattern( "hh:mm a" ) 
    .withLocale( Locale.CANADA )
```

### Specify locale

The indicator for day/night is a matter for [localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization). Some locales use AM/PM. Some use am/pm. Some use a.m./p.m. And still others use I-don’t-know-what.

Your code neglects to specify a [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) object. So your [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) implicitly relies upon the JVM’s current default locale.

I would bet that the current default locale of the JVM in your own machine differs from that of your Docker environment.

The best solution is to **avoid needlessly relying on the JVM’s current default locale**.  Specify explicitly. (By the way, ditto for time zone.)

To specify locale, call [`DateTimeFormatter#withLocale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withLocale(java.util.Locale)). Keep in mind that *java.time* uses [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). So the `withLocale` method generates and returns a new fresh `DateTimeFormatter` object rather than altering (“mutating”) the original.

```java
Locale locale = Locale.US ;
DateTimeFormatter f = 
    DateTimeFormatter
        .ofPattern( … ) 
        .withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = myLocalTime.format( f ) ;
```

That is just one example. You will need to determine for yourself the appropriate locale that meets your expectations.

#### Exploring locales

If you want to see which locales use which day/night indicators, write some code to loop all locales provided in your JDK.

```java
final LocalTime time = LocalTime.of ( 12 , 30 );
final DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "hh:mm a" );
Locale
        .availableLocales ( )
        .forEach ( ( Locale locale ) ->
                System.out.println (
                        time.format ( f.withLocale ( locale ) )
                                .concat ( " | " )
                                .concat ( locale.getDisplayName ( Locale.US ) )
                                .concat ( " | " )
                                .concat ( locale.toString ( ) )
                )
        );
```

When run on Java 21 from Azul Systems:

```
12:30 PM |  | 
12:30 אחה״צ | Hebrew | he
12:30 หลังเที่ยง | Thai (Thai, Thailand) | th_TH_#Thai
12:30 PM | Low German | nds
12:30 günortadan soň | Turkmen (Latin, Turkmenistan) | tk_TM_#Latn
12:30 ድ.ቀ. | Tigrinya (Ethiopia) | ti_ET
12:30 பிற்பகல் | Tamil (Singapore) | ta_SG
12:30 pēcpusdienā | Latvian | lv
12:30 pm | English (Niue) | en_NU
12:30 下午 | Chinese (Simplified, Singapore) | zh_SG_#Hans
12:30  | Fula (Adlam, Liberia) | ff_LR_#Adlm
12:30 pm | English (Jamaica) | en_JM
12:30 PM | Kako | kkj
…
12:30 p. m. | Spanish (Nicaragua) | es_NI
12:30 ꁯꋒ | Sichuan Yi (Yi, China) | ii_CN_#Yiii
12:30 Ɛndámâ | Masai (Tanzania) | mas_TZ
12:30 منجهند، شام | Sindhi (Pakistan) | sd_PK
12:30 ድ.ቀ. | Tigrinya | ti
12:30 PTG | Malay (Brunei) | ms_BN
12:30 PM | Chakma (India) | ccp_IN
12:30 G.M. | Breton (France) | br_FR
```

#### Locales change

Human cultures evolve and change. And so the localization rules in a `Locale` may change over time.

In a case like yours where you expect a specific behavior from a locale, you should  **write tests to verify the locale** actually behaves the way you expect. For example, a locale that today uses `a.m.` may tomorrow use `am`.

FYI, most implementations of modern Java by default rely upon the [Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository)  by the [Unicode Consortium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_Consortium) for its localization rules. The [CLDR is periodically updated](https://cldr.unicode.org/index/downloads), typically 2-5 times per year. Newer [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) releases typically include one of the most recent releases of the CLDR.